# User master database from Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-warehouse

I have procedures in my Azure Data Warehouse that need to create other Azure Databases, then populate them with data from the DW.  Is there way for a stored procedure in an Azure Data Warehouse to create a separate Azure DB?  Then possibly create tables and populate them in that newly created Azure DB?

Comment: what is the need for creating azure database from stored procedures of dw?

Comment: The DW will house data for all years of our data and requests will come in to do further analytics on a slice of that data.  The expense of leaving the DW on 24/7 and the concurrent queries limitation makes it prohibitive to have all of our clients directly query the DW.

So dumping that slice of data to an Azure Database was the idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate on creating database and tables part,whether they should be dynamic or one time population

Comment: I have about 30 tables of source data that is by year (4-5 billion rows per table).  A client will need to see all data for a particular year.  I need to create those same 30 tables in an Azure Database and populate them with the slice of data from the DW tables.  Currently, it is procedure based, pretty much the only dynamic portion is the new databases name, then using that newly created DBs fully qualified name for all of the INSERT statements (from DW to new DB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create sqldatabase from storedprocedures ..even if they are in same server..Here we are dealing with two  different logical servers(DW and SQLdatabase)

2.For the insertion part,you can try cross database queries ,but cross database queries from  [azureDW to SQLAzure database is not supported](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/)..

Few options,i could think off..

Create a windows application,which does the below
 1.create a sqlazure database ,if not exist
 2.create tables in SQLdatabase,if they don't exist
 3.finally read the data from SQLDW and insert it into SQLdatabase

Comment: I've got a handle on 1 and 2 but number 3 is the difficult part.  How would you read a table in SQLDW from SQLdatabase?  External Data source and external table throws an error.  Doing the inverse, adding the SQLDatabase as an external datasource and table to SQLDW doesn't seem to be supported either.

Comment: use different connections,in connection1 read data from DW and populate to datatable ,now that datatable is populated ,do insert into sqldatabase

Comment: @BamBamBeano If the data is too big for TheGameiswar's suggestion, and you have access to it, you could use SSIS to do some or all of  this - chuck in some script tasks that do the first two steps, then just regular data flow for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

For efficient data transfer between the two databases, you could use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx). The same code could create the database and tables.

For scheduling this you could use something like [Elastic Database Jobs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqlemea/2016/11/04/elastic-database-jobs-sample-for-running-t-sql-code-on-multiple-databases/).